# Bluethooth doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, vaio, sony, blackberry

I've Sony Vaio E Series laptop VPCEH3AEA, while I was installing Ubuntu 12.10, the bluetooth worked well.

After finishing the installation process, there was a problem that when I tried to activate bluetooth, it should be working but it doesn't work at all.

The slide button of bluetooth setting never goes to the on option and the hardware indicates it work, plus I can't connect my laptop with my BB.

Is there a solution?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

yes it does.

Open 
*Ubuntu Software Center*
 look up for 
*bluez-tools* 
and install it,
 with the 
*OBEX* add-on.

you can install some bluetooh managers if you want.
just look up *bluetooth* on *Ubuntu Software Center*
but the original one is fine.